# browser.alarms is undefined using webextension-polyfill

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox-addon-webextensions, webextension-polyfill

I'm trying to create an alarm using `browser.alarms` API for web extensions.
To make the extension cross-browser, I am using webextension-polyfill and testing on Chrome.

My code to create an alarm within a background script is shown below:

```
browser.alarms.create('spline-items-notification', {
  periodInMinutes: 1
});
```

However, when I attempt to run this extension, I always get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
```

I am loading webextension-polyfill before the background script in manifest.json, and other interfaces work, like `browser.notifications`.

I would like to know how to fix this if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [alarms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/alarms)
>   To use this API you need to have the "alarms" permission.

Does the `manifest.json` have the "alarms" permission?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just tested this and indeed that was the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

I think this a bug with [webextension-polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill), but I opened a [pull request](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill/pull/212) that should fix it.